# Dot Local file to deal with DLL Hell issues?

Tags: dll

I've read that placing an empty file named `<AppName>.exe.local` in the application directory will cause the application to look in that directory first for `DLLs` and `OCXs` so as to avoid issues with conflicting `DLLs` and `OCXs` found elsewhere on the system.

But doesn't the application first look in the application directory anyway?  What effect does the `.local` file actually have?

Answer (score 2):

To be frank, I've never heard of the `.local` scheme before, but a quick search brought up [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/01/24/517221.aspx) which quite explains it:

> For an application foo.exe, if there is a file foo.exe.local exists, Windows will first look at foo.exe’s application directory, before start the regular dll search. To mitigate the COM problem, the redirection applies both to full path dll loading, as well as partial name loading.

It appears that the `.local` file forces even absolute-path searches to the application directory first, whereas usually absolute paths are unchanged and only relative paths follow the [DLL search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: would you need to register the DLLs/OCXs that are in the application directory?

Comment: I would think not. The local files serve as a replacement to the system files (possibly already registered) so I don't think you will have to register those.

Answer (score 1):

> Applications can depend on a specific
>   version of a shared DLL and start to
>   fail if another application is
>   installed with a newer or older
>   version of the same DLL. There are two
>   ways to ensure that your application
>   uses the correct DLL: DLL redirection
>   and side-by-side components.
>   Developers and administrators should
>   use DLL redirection for existing
>   applications, because it does not
>   require any changes to the
>   application. If you are creating a new
>   application or updating an application
>   and want to isolate your application
>   from potential problems, create a
>   side-by-side component.

Ref.: [Dynamic-Link Library Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682600%28VS.85%29.aspx)